# How to createStore with composeWithDevTools in Typescript without type errors?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

In my index.tsx I create redux store

```
import { createStore, Store } from 'redux';
...
const store: Store = createStore(reducers, {});
```

Now I try to add composeWithDevTools

```
import { createStore, Store, compose } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
...
const store: Store = createStore(reducers, {}, compose(composeWithDevTools()));
```

and what I get is the error

```
Type 'Store<CombinedState<{ general: any; }>, StoreAction>' is not assignable to type 'Store<any, AnyAction>'.
  Types of property 'dispatch' are incompatible.
    Type 'Dispatch<StoreAction>' is not assignable to type 'Dispatch<AnyAction>'.
      Type 'AnyAction' is not assignable to type 'StoreAction'.  TS2322
```

Looks like it is somehow related with my StoreAction type.
In my reducers I have following

```
export default (state: GeneralState = initialState, action: StoreAction) => {
...
};
```

and StoreAction is

```
type StoreAction = {
  type: string;
  payload: any;
};
```

And this StoreAction `type` is incompatible with AnyAction `interface`. I don't understand how can I fix it correctly from TypeScript perspective.

Any ideas how can I fix the error?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you don't need to wrap `composeWithDevTools` in a `compose` statement.

From the docs:

```
  const composedEnhancers = composeWithDevTools(...enhancers)
  const store = createStore(rootReducer, preloadedState, composedEnhancers)
```

https://redux.js.org/recipes/configuring-your-store/